# knockout anonymous computed observable executing more than once

Tags: knockout.js, anonymous, computed-observable

Recently I bumped on rather weird code in the project I'm currently working on. Here is the isolated example depicting the issue:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" data-bind = "value: firstName">
    <input type="text" data-bind = "value: lastName">
  <br />  <br />
  <span data-bind = "text: firstName"></span>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var myViewModelProto = function(){
    self = this;
    this.firstName = ko.observable("John");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Smith");

    ko.computed(function(){
        alert(self.lastName());
    });
};

var vm = new myViewModelProto();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The alert in **anonymous** computed observable will fire not only when viewModel is created, but also **each time** a dependent observable (lastName in this case) is changed **after** constructor function is complete. In the code I'm maintaining right now this is used to run specific code to redraw bound ui widgets.
So my questions are:

1. Is this a bug in knockout which eventually be fixed? (So I'd better remove this magic whatsoever, before it will stop working after update)
2. Is this a common pattern of sorts and perfectly fine to use?

UPDATE:
In the real case I encountered in the project I need to maintain there are several lines of code in place of alert with no direct references to a dependent observable, value of observable is changed in some nested function calls made from within computed. The example given is extremely simplified. Also, both computed observables are decorated with throttle extender which is probably was sole purpose of making them computed in first place.

Comment: Why did you create the `computed` in the first place?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? It's not a bug... that's exactly how a computed observable is supposed to work. The value is calculated on creation, and updates when other observables it depends on is updated.

Comment: I expect **anonymous** computed observable to be executed exactly once upon declaration. Since it's value cannot be read there is no point executing it anymore. I expect it to resemble [pure computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) behavior to an extent. No name > no subscribers > no execution.

Comment: You are thinking of a computed observable as a value. While it can be that, there is no requirement stating it has to. Maybe it'll make it easier to think of a computed as a callback function. In the case of an anonymous computed, its like a callback function without a return value vs a named computed resembling a callback function that returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

When a function (including `computed` function) is reading the value of some observable, Knockout automatically creates a *dependency* between the two. Once the observable value has changed, all dependent functions will be re-evaluated.

However, you can explicitly instruct Knockout *not* to create a dependency using the `peek()` method:

```
ko.computed(function(){
    alert(self.lastName.peek());
});
```

See ["How dependency tracking works"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html)

Comment: That's a valid explanation _why_ does this happen, but the question was if it is a intended (and not a side-) effect of knockout and if it's a good practice to put some logic in such functions. Personally I would't expect an anonymous and thus unreadable computed observable to execute it's code after constructor function is done.

Comment: Of course it's intended. Many people take advantage of this behavior to detect deep changes in the model as a whole by calling `ko.toJSON()` inside a `computed` in order to create that dependency and subscribe for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the computed function will call each time when there is a change in the value of any observable which used inside this function.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html